# Why can't static member methods access its non-static method in C++?

Tags: c++

I had to make a callback interface for a new module while I work, so I made a static method in a class.

One thing I still don't understand is why I can't call a non-static member method in a static member like this :

```
class CAdapterUser
{
public:
    CAdapterUser()          {}
    virtual ~CAdapterUser() {}

    void        Test();
    void        Test2();

protected:
    CAdapter    m_Adapter;

    unsigned char buffer[16];

    static void TestFunc(void* apContext);
};

void 
CAdapterUser::TestFunc( void* apContext )
{
//  CAdapterUser* pUser = (CAdapterUser*)apContext;
    CAdapterUser* pUser = reinterpret_cast<CAdapterUser*>(apContext);

    pUser->Test2();         // Compile error : LNK2019
    pUser->buffer[0] = 1;   // Even though I can access protected member variable?
}
```

Could someone answer my question?

Comment: Did you actually add a function definition for `Test2`?  A link error suggest you did not.

Comment: Because if it can it will be a non-static member function?

Comment: @tntxtnt OP is using `pUser->Test2();` not `this->Test2();`. It should be fine.

Comment: Oh, my mistake..thank you for your advice.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019
Maybe OP haven't defined `Test2()` yet.

Comment: @tntxtnt - Clearly they haven't defined `Test2`. But what do static data members have to do with it?

Comment: Sorry it's just something I copied from google should have posted the link. Update it now

Comment: @tntxtnt Whenever you copy somebody else's words/work, you should use "quotation formatting" to indicate that it is not your words/work. Or when the words don't apply to the topic at all, maybe just don't copy them at all ;)

Answer (score 1):

LNK2019 is unresolved symbol, probably you simply forgot to implement `Test2()`.

Comment: Oh, my mistake..thank you for your advice.